# Sentry run test in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, sentry

I'm trying to run a simple test in ionic using Sentry, I'm kind of a new to Ionic dev and what I was able to do is simply capture error in Ionic by following this [doc](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/cordova/ionic/) but I want to run this as a test, and I'm trying to run some test in `app.component.spec.ts` file

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://9f96f00e3307482cad702de5b47f85d1@o613526.ingest.sentry.io/5749220' });
  . . .
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryIonicErrorHandler}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should rise the error and  Log in Sentry', () => {
    const i = 4;
    expect(i).toEqual(5);
  });
```

In this test it doesn't log in sentry dashboard what I have done wrong here ?, Is this my test correct ?